# Building rocket.chat on heroku server faced error

Tags: heroku, rocket.chat

I wanted to deploy the [rocket.chat](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat) project on heroku, following the deployment instruction, I have encountered the following error:

"
**Can't open /tmp/build_29c97eef7e456d21231bc9eb4751ca67/ringelco-racket-chat-a864ad48b50652f34205d656e8e6d93976ce69e3/packages/rocketchat-livechat/plugin/build.sh**
/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/tap_i18n/.1.8.2.10lihy6.24zh++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.tap-i18n-compiler.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:116
      throw error;
"

I have noticed that some other issues are related to such error ([this](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/8838) and [this](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/7583)), but nobody has answered it yet!

It would be appreciative if you could help me.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: The problem was that I have used the development branch.

Answer (score 2):

Issue fixed. 
I just pulled the latest code from [Rocket.Chat](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat).
Followed the step to deploy it on Heroku [Rocket.Chat Herokyu Deployment](https://docs.rocket.chat/installation/paas-deployments/heroku/).
You have to use buildpack  https://github.com/RocketChat/meteor-buildpack-horse.git.

Comment: I have used the same Code and followed the deployment steps, but still have the error. 
Which settings of Heroku do you use?

Comment: default setting, whatever used in Rocket.Chat.

Comment: @ShaileshKumarKachhi : Thanks  a lot. My issue resolved. 1 Hit